# Calling a function via conditional statement in php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have defined a function as below and trying to recursively call it on certain condition. I have done through `if else` but want to implement it through a `conditional statement`.

```
function rand_num(){
    global $conn;
    $random_number = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
    $sql = "select * from table where project_enumber = ".$random_number;
    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    (mysqli_num_rows($run))?rand_num():return $random_number;

    /*conditional statement*/
}
```

Comment: I think `if`-`else` is already entailing a conditional statement.Do you mean you want to use something like a `switch`?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is to generate a UNIQUE in-existent random number into a database.

You can go through a more clearer approach here as below:

```
function rand_num() {
    global $conn;
    $random_number = mt_rand(10000, 99999);

    $sql = "select * from table where project_enumber = " . $random_number;
    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    return mysqli_num_rows($run) ? false : $random_number;
}

function newFunc() {
    // continue until a random number greater than 0 is received
    while(!$rand_num = rand_num())
        continue;

    $rand_num; // Your desired result
}
```

This will prevent recursive call and appears to be a more cleaner approach.

**EDIT**

As pointed by @Syscall, `rand_num()` will now return the random number

Comment: In your answer, `rand_num()` returns the number of rows, not a random number, right?

Comment: @Syscall Yes, if you're talking about the naming convention for `rand_num()` then name `$rand_num` is given to store the response from `rand_num` function.

Comment: No, I was talking about that : in `$rand_num = rand_num()`, `$rand_num` will contains the number of the rows, not the wanted random number. I think your approach could be clean, but seems not working in this state. How do you get the random number from `rand_num()`?

Comment: @Syscall I've updated the answer to return the random number when its in-existent in DB.

Comment: It's better now :)

Comment: @AshishChoudhary , you have got the code and its objective, but I want to confirm, Is calling a function through the loop is more efficient than recursion?

Comment: @Abhi Yes. Loop will call a function and will destroy its scope in every iteration so less memory consumption and garbage. While, Recursion  waits for the response from recursive function and will again go inside recursion... It will keep on building memory and garbage until it finds the solution and breaks from it.
Loop is like "I didn't got anything from this iteration so forget this and move to another"
Recursion is like "inception" movie - "I didn't got anything from this iteration but I will not forget this iteration and continue to go into deeper levels until i find the solution"

Answer (score 0):

You could format your return statement as follow:

```
return mysqli_num_rows($run) ? rand_num() : $random_number;
```

You have to return something, but it's the return "data" that change.

In the first case (true), it returns the data of the recursive function.
In the second case (false), it returns the `$random_number`.

It is equals to:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($run)) return rand_num();
else return $random_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if and else` condition as:

```
function rand_num(){
        global $conn;
        $random_number = mt_rand(10000, 99999);

        $sql = "select * from table where project_enumber = ".$random_number;
        $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0){
      rand_num();
    }else{
     return $random_number;       /*conditional statement*/      
    }

}
```

Comment: At Line `rand_num();` it should be `return rand_num();`

Comment: I think it's not required. It will also as it is.

Comment: This function will fail in second iteration of `rand_num()` as the random number is not returned.